# Perl SQLite DBI INSERT via an Array

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi

I have the following pretty complex Perl code that is fed by a dynamic array varying in size but typically between 10 and 20 rows.  I'm therefore running this in a loop but reckon there must be a more elegant way of inserting the data.

Is it possible to improve this code to make it more efficient?

```
sub data_fill {

  my $target = shift;
  my (@input_data) = @_;

  # Delete the old data
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM work_data WHERE target = '$target' ");
  $sth->execute();

  # Insert the new data
  my $sql       = qq{INSERT INTO work_data (target, trackingno, temp, apple, orange, banana, strawberry, lettuce, apricot, peach, blackberry, melon, lemon) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)};
  my $sth       = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  my $arraysize = scalar(@input_data);
  my $i         = 0;

  while ($i < $arraysize) {

    $sth->bind_param(1, $target,             SQL_VARCHAR);
    $sth->bind_param(2, 'OK',                SQL_VARCHAR);
    $sth->bind_param(3, $input_data[$i],     SQL_VARCHAR);
    $sth->bind_param(4, $input_data[$i + 1], SQL_VARCHAR);
    $sth->bind_param(5, $input_data[$i + 2], SQL_VARCHAR);
    $sth->bind_param(6, $input_data[$i + 3], SQL_VARCHAR);
    $sth->bind_param(7, $input_data[$i + 4], SQL_VARCHAR);

    my $lettuce = $input_data[$i + 5];
    my $apricot = $input_data[$i + 6];
    my $peach   = $input_data[$i + 7];

    if (length($lettuce) == 0) {
      $lettuce = -1;
    }    # Safety net to help later in db sorting
    if (length($apricot) == 0) {
      $apricot = -1;
    }    # Safety net to help later in db sorting
    if (length($peach) == 0) {
      $peach = -1;
    }    # Safety net to help later in db sorting

    $sth->bind_param(8,  $lettuce,             SQL_INTEGER);
    $sth->bind_param(9,  $apricot,             SQL_INTEGER);
    $sth->bind_param(10, $peach,               SQL_INTEGER);
    $sth->bind_param(11, $input_data[$i + 8],  SQL_VARCHAR);
    $sth->bind_param(12, $input_data[$i + 9],  SQL_VARCHAR);
    $sth->bind_param(13, $input_data[$i + 10], SQL_VARCHAR);
    $sth->execute;

    $i = $i + 11;    # INCREMENT
  }
  $dbh->disconnect;
  return;
}
```

Comment: At a glance, why not use the `sqlite_see_if_its_a_number` attribute so you don't have to call `bind_param` a million times and then simply pass the list of bind values to `execute`, e.g. `$sth->execute(@input_data);`?

Comment: What version of Perl are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not so much complex as convoluted.

The first thing I see is that `$dbh->prepare` is called every time the subroutine executes. Worse still, there is a `$dbh->disconnect` before the return.

I would also look at the binding, which could be permanent if you copied the parameters to a static array instead of binding them all every time.

---

**Update**

This is to try to explain what I mean. The code inside the `unless` statement will be executed only once - the first time the `data_fill` subroutine is called. It prepares the delete and insert statements, and binds the `@params` array to the place holders in the insert statement.

Note that the `prepare` and `bind_param` calls don't have to be within this subroutine. They are really part of initialisation, and the `unless` is there to make sure that they are executed only once.

Once all that has been set up, all that remains is to execute the `delete` statement, and then repeatedly fill the `@params` array from the subroutine parameter list and execute the `insert` statement. I have removed the `$dbh->close` altogether as it's not the right place to be closing the database handle.

This solution has far too many *"magic numbers"* in it, and I wouldn't publish it as it stands, but I don't know enough of your requirement totell whether I'm even on the right lines.

Note that none of this is tested, beyond checking that it will compile

```
my ($delete, $insert, @params);

sub data_fill {

  my $target = shift;
  my (@input_data) = @_;

  unless ($delete and $insert) {

    $delete = $dbh->prepare('DELETE FROM work_data WHERE target = ?');

    $insert = $dbh->prepare('
        INSERT INTO work_data (
          target, trackingno, temp, apple, orange, banana,
          strawberry, lettuce, apricot, peach, blackberry, melon, lemon
        )
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ');

    for my $i (0 .. 10) {
      my $mode = SQL_VARCHAR;
      $mode = SQL_INTEGER if $i >= 7 and $i <= 9;
      $sth->bind_param($i+1, $params[$i], $mode);
    }
  }

  $delete->execute($target);

  while (@input_data >= 11) {
    my @record = splice @input_data, 0, 11;
    @params = ($target, 'OK', @record);
    for (@params[7..9]) {
      $_ = -1 unless length > 0;
    }
    $insert->execute;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had to tweak your code slightly but it worked, thanks for the knowledge :)

Comment: @HeavyHead: If there is a mistake in my code then please tell me about it so that I can fix it. Many other people will be reading this post in search of help, and it would be very wrong to offer them faulty solution.